# Change order of multiple paths of gcc?

Tags: windows, bash, shell, gcc, command-line

I am using Windows 10 with limited experience in compilers.

In command prompt `where gcc` returns:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe`

How can I change the order if I want the second one to be the priority?

This is because when I execute certain `Go` code (go get github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/...) I get the error like :

`cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in..`

So it seems to be 32 bit vs 64 bit versions mismatch. Although I can delete the version corresponding to 32 bit I want to know how to change order if one has multiple. Thanks.

Comment: Set your PATH in the order you want them selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate miken32 the steps are:

1. Open `Advanced system settings` by simply searching on the search bar.
2. Click on `Environment variables`

[image]

3. Double click on `path` under `system variables`
   [image]
4. Use `Move up` or `Move down` to ensure the order. 
   [image]